# How to project a 3D plane on to another 3D plane by linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, plane-geometry

I have two 3D planes represented by their `<surface normal, one point>`:

```
Plane_1 = <N1, V1> 
Plane_2 = <N2, V2>
```

Then I want to project the Plane_1 onto the Plane_2 along Plane_1's surface normal direction `N1`.

Let `a1, b1, and c1` are points on the Plane_1. After projection, what are the corresponding locations of `a2, b2 and c2`?

I know one solution is constructing a ray `R1` starting at `a1` with direction `N1`. Then `a2` is the intersection of `R1` and `Plane_2`. However, if there is a matrix or another elegant representation of the results of this projection?

Thank you for any reply!

Comment: Orthogonal projection refers to projecting along a line normal to the plane you are projecting **to**. By using the word "orthogonally" in an unusual way you are inviting answers that answer the wrong question. The projection you apparently want is generally called an oblique projection.

Comment: Thank you for correcting it! I have modified my question!

Comment: The answer also has been modified. You should look into it.

Answer (score 2):

The projector of a point $\mathbf{P} (x, y, z)$ onto a plane (the second plane) along the direction of the normal of the first plane $\mathbf{d}$ is given by

$ \mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{P_0} + (\mathbf{I} - \dfrac{\mathbf{dn}^T}{\mathbf{d}^T \mathbf{n}} ) ( \mathbf{P} - \mathbf{P_0}) $

where $\mathbf{P_0}$ is any point on the second plane, and $\mathbf{n}$ is the normal vector of the second plane, while $\mathbf{d}$ is the unit vector of the first plane.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I need.